# AWS Sagemaker : No response back from the endpoint "HTTP 301 293"

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, gunicorn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to host custom docker container through sagemaker. 
Im using nginx, gunicorn, flask setup. 
I'm able to invoke(ping) the endpoint for my application.
input to my service is 'application/json' format and expected output from the service is json.

When i call the service i get following output in the client :

```
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2Final//EN">\n<title>Redirecting...</title>\n<h1>Redirecting...</h1>\n<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://boaucpph.aws.local:8080/invocations/">http://boaucpph.aws.local:8080/invocations/</a>.  If not click the link.'
```

and my endpoint logs tell :

```
10.32.0.2 - - [28/Mar/2018:20:50:41 +0000] "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 301 293 "-" "AHC/2.0"
```

my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off; # Prevent forking

pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  # defaults
}

 http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

  upstream gunicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }

    location / {
      return 404 "{}";
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone faced similar problem ? any suggestions on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. 
The issue was in my flask file.

Initially the endpoint in my flask file was this.

```
@app.route('/invocations/', methods=['POST'])
```

had to change it into

```
@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
```

Since in the nginx file server will send requests to

```
 location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
```

i.e.

```
~/invocations
```

Since there was one extra / in flask app, it wasn't recieving the request.